# Case with doctrine2, symfony2 and postgresql entities

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, entities

I have a problem with doctrine2 in symfony2 app with postgres database.

I get error:

```
SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR: schema "main" does not exist
```

Problem is that my schema is Main not main. When I rename it, similar thing happends for table relation:

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "main.brand_brandid_seq" does not exist
```

Problem is case sensitivity and I guess maybe it have something to do with quoting or some doctrine configuration.

Entity:

```
namespace MyB\Entity;

/**
 * MyB\Entity\Brand
 *
 * @orm:Table(name="Main.Brand")
 * @orm:Entity
 */
class Brand
{
    /**
     * @var integer $brandid
     *
     * @orm:Column(name="BrandId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @orm:Id
     * @orm:GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @orm:SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="Main.Brand_BrandId_seq", allocationSize="1", initialValue="1")
     */
    private $brandid;

    /**
     * @var string $brandname
     *
     * @orm:Column(name="BrandName", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     */
    private $brandname;

    /**
     * Set name.
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->brandname = $name;
    }
}
```

Schema:

```
SET search_path = "Main", pg_catalog;

CREATE SEQUENCE "Brand_BrandId_seq"
    START WITH 2
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MAXVALUE
    NO MINVALUE
    CACHE 1;


SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;


CREATE TABLE "Brand" (
    "BrandId" integer DEFAULT nextval('"Brand_BrandId_seq"'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    "BrandName" character varying(32) NOT NULL
);
```

Controller:

```
        $reseller = new \MyB\Entity\Brand();
        $reseller->setName('Sasa');

        $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $em->persist($reseller);
        $em->flush();
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
namespace MyB\Entity;

/**
 * MyB\Entity\Brand
 *
 * @orm:Table(name="""Main"".""Brand""")
 * @orm:Entity
 */
class Brand
{
    /**
     * @var integer $brandid
     *
     * @orm:Column(name="""BrandId""", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @orm:Id
     * @orm:GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @orm:SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="""Main"".""Brand_BrandId_seq""", allocationSize="1", initialValue="1")
     */
    private $brandid;

    /**
     * @var string $brandname
     *
     * @orm:Column(name="""BrandName""", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     */
    private $brandname;

    /**
     * Set name.
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->brandname = $name;
    }
}
```

In postgres every word case sensitive must be escape.

Answer (score 1):

When using escaped table names take care about this "bug" : https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/615 . Doctrine takes the first character of the table name as aliasprefix and thus a quote is used, crushing all your SQLs

Answer (score 0):

I write PpSqlBundle but it isn't finished yet, but you could try, I think it should work.
It can generate form db same as in symfony. in config.yml you should have:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   
            dbname:   
            host:     
            user:     
            password: 
            driverClass: PgSqlBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver # it's important
            logging:
```

and you should use command

```
app/console doctrine:mapping:import Yourbundlename annotation
```

https://github.com/mstrzele/PgSqlBundle

Comment: Thanks, but it throws: The given 'driverClass' PgSqlBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver has to implement the \Doctrine\DBAL\Driver interface.

Comment: And it does. To install you should have i to register namespace:

Comment: for example: 'PgSqlBundle'      => __DIR__.'/../src', and register bundle: new PgSqlBundle\PgSqlBundle(),

Comment: I use symfony2 pr10 with vendors

Comment: Yes, thanks. But there is no gSqlBundle\PgSqlBundle class on https://github.com/mstrzele/PgSqlBundle.

Comment: After adding it I got:    
Warning: Missing argument 1 for PgSqlBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\PostgreSqlSchemaManager::initConfig(), 

Warning: Missing argument 2 for PgSqlBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\PostgreSqlSchemaManager::initConfig(), 

Notice: Undefined variable: name in PgSqlBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\PostgreSqlSchemaManager.php on line 414
                                                
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                 
  Unknown column type datetimepgsql requested.

Comment: Cause you don't have good file. Now it is in github. It is my fault I forggot to push it.

Comment: Thanks. Now I got  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                    
  Index '' does not exist on table 'Main"."SomeTable'.  Seems like my table: -- Table: "Main"."SomeTable"

-- DROP TABLE "Main"."SomeTable";

CREATE TABLE "Main"."SomeTable"
(
  "SomeTableId" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Main"."SomeTable_SomeTable_seq"'::regclass),
  "ProductId" integer,
  "SomeTableId" integer
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "Main"."SomeTable" OWNER TO postgres; is bad.

Comment: In doctrine2 you must have indexes on every column with foreign key and primary key must be on every table, even in many to many tables,it that case you have primary key on two column.

Comment: As I see you don't have primary key on "Main"."SomeTable"

Comment: Added it, now I get :    Importing mapping information from "default" entity manager
  > writing MyB/Entity/Base/System.SomeTableMappedSuperclass.php
  > writing MyB/Entity/System.SomeTable.php

Notice: Undefined property: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo::$tableName in PgSqlBundle\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator.php on line 871

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '{' in MyB\Entity\Base\System.SomeTableMappedSuperclass.php on line 10

Comment: Looks like class names are in format Schema.TableNameMappedSuperclass, and this dot is what causing an error. Isn't it better to have namespace under Entity namespage for each schema? Any suggestion how to fix this? P.S. Thank you very much for the effort!

Comment: In one file was bug in case sensitive. On github is fixed

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo::$tableName in PgSqlBundle\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator.php on line 871 I can send you generated entity if you prefer.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '{' in MyB\Entity\Base\System.SomeTableMappedSuperclass.php on line 10

Comment: Great, thanks. Now it generates entities, but I get a number of notices like this: Notice: Undefined property: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo::$tableName in PgSqlBundle\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator.php on line 871

Comment: And some of my tables and schemas have names that are PHP keywords like global and switch :) Example: public function setSwitchid(\MyB\Entity\Global\Switch $switchid)
    {
        $this->switchid = $switchid;
    } and then I get error for that line: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SWITCH, expecting T_STRING in MyB\Entity\System\Base\SomeTableMappedSuperclass.php on line 176 and it stops generating!

Comment: And some namespace declaration are invalid, because they contain keywords. Can that be escaped somehow?

Comment: It's may git-plugin in eclipse I had some problems. How it's up to date.

Comment: Can I send you some files via email or somehow?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SWITCH, expecting T_STRING in MyB\Entity\System\Base\SomeTableSuperclass.php on line 176, and line 176 says: public function setSwitchid(\MyB\Entity\System\Switch $switchid); Class name is PHP keyword, that is the problem.

Comment: Yes, it reached me. Word global and switch are keywords and you cannot use it in classname namespace nor method name. The thing what it should be done is use naming strategy in generating process. Doctrine2 don't have such machanizm, but my plugin will be have in next week. Before that everything what you can do is change manualy your entities or make change in your database. I notice that it is problem with sequence name in your entities but I am fixing that and for the moment fix will be in github.

Comment: Can you just tell me where can I apply changes to your code to change anmespaces to have name SchemaSchemaName/TableNameEntity? Thanks.

Comment: PgSqlBundle/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DatabaseDriver.php, line 108
change
$className = Inflector::classify(strtolower($tableName));
to

Comment: $className = 'Schema'. Inflector::classify(strtolower($tableName)) . 'Entity';

Comment: But shortly will be posibility in config to bind custom naming strategy

Comment: sequencers name are now fixed in github

Comment: Argh, now it throws  PDOException SQLSTATE[42602]: Invalid name: 7 ERROR: invalid name syntax
LINE 1: SELECT NEXTVAL('"Main"."DeviceType"_"DeviceTypeId"_seq') when I try to write to db :(

Comment: This error happends when I remove driverClass: PgSqlBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver from config. I though this is just needed for entity generation. Thanks again to @mstrzele for valuable help. Now my entities work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using migration files on Laravel. Change     Schema::table to     Schema::create. This might help someone.