# Doctrine ORM table with schema annotation

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Schema and table name in Postgres are case sensitive. How can I specify correct schema in docblock annotations so they are not converted to lowercase?

Neither of these works:

```
@Table(name="MySchema.MyTable") // gets converted to lowercase
@Table(name="`MySchema`.`MyTable`") // invalid table
@Table(name="`MySchema.MyTable`") // also invalid table
```

Doctrine ORM is 2.0.4

Theres no word about schema in documentation either, only found that schema param/keyword is no longer supported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case problem with doctrine2, symfony2 and postgresql entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573865/case-problem-with-doctrine2-symfony2-and-postgresql-entities)

Comment: @Ross - Solution in mentioned thread works, thanks.

Comment: @Ross, you might want to put this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573865/case-problem-with-doctrine2-symfony2-and-postgresql-entities) thread, Postgres is case-sensitive and each word must be escaped:

```
@Table(name="""MySchema"".""MyTable""")
```